# Optimize storage size for a very large table

Tags: mysql

I have a huge number of rows (billions) of the following schema in MySQL on the MyISAM storage engine. Any suggestions for how to store this more efficiently (storage wise)?

```
mysql> describe options;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| stockid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| strike        | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| symbol        | varchar(63)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last          | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| chg           | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bid           | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ask           | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expirydate    | varchar(63)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ticker        | varchar(63)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| expiry        | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type          | varchar(63)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| datecaptured  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| volume        | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| openint       | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastclosedate | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| row_id        | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: `int(11)` probably isn't as large as believed - it is has no more capacity than `int(2)`. If this is truly "billions", that'll be an issue.

Comment: The columns last/chg/bid/ask look like market price related values, and `FLOAT` is a very dangerous data type choice where money is involved unless you're okay with imprecise, approximated values, which is the tradeoff that makes `FLOAT` is so relatively space-efficient.  Are you familiar with its limitations?

Comment: Yes indeed -- is the practice to store the money as INT *100? Or is there a better model?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious problems here are storing dates as strings, that uses more space than necessary and makes indexing impractical. You'll also want to examine why the first column is set to the irregular `INT(10) UNSIGNED` type instead of a default `INT(11)`.

If you want really compact tables you might want to experiment with the [`ARCHIVE` engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/archive-storage-engine.html) type. It has append-only tables, but they're compressed and can hold a lot of data without needing to be trimmed or pruned. The downside is they don't index as well, but that doesn't seem to be a problem for you here.

Note: MyISAM is a very old and brittle storage engine so if you can migrate away from it to InnoDB you'll be better off. Since MyISAM has no journal it can't recover easily from server crashes and can easily become corrupted beyond repair. InnoDB is able to bounce back from most and in cases where it can't, you can still read-only dump it and use the data elsewhere.

If `SHOW TABLE STATUS` doesn't indicate a problem with storage, don't worry about it. Hard drives are cheap, even the SSD variety.